# Why I can't use method from one of my .py files in another .py file?

Tags: python, selenium

This is my code for form with button:

```
import sys
from ClickerBot import test_ClikerBot

def func1():
    if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
        # Python 2
        import Tkinter as tk
    else:
        # Python 3
        import tkinter as tk
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title(“Clicker”)

   def startClick():
        root.destroy()
        clicker = test_ClikerBot()
        clicker.test_clicker_bot()

   button1 = tk.Button(root, text=“CLICK CLICK CLICK”, command=startClick())
    button1.pack()
    tk.mainloop()

if __name__ == ‘__main__‘:
    func1()
```

When I start this file, I receive next error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7    /Users/ltst/Desktop/dev/DribbleBot/venv/Scripts/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File “/Users/ltst/Desktop/dev/DribbleBot/venv/Scripts/main.py”, line 23, in <module>
    func1()
  File “/Users/ltst/Desktop/dev/DribbleBot/venv/Scripts/main.py”, line 19, in func1
    button1 = tk.Button(root, text=“CLICK CLICK CLICK”, command=startClick())
  File “/Users/ltst/Desktop/dev/DribbleBot/venv/Scripts/main.py”, line 16, in startClick
    clicker = test_ClikerBot()
  File “/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py”, line 191, in __init__
    (self.__class__, methodName))
ValueError: no such test method in <class ‘ClickerBot.test_ClikerBot’>: runTest
```

But in my ClickerBot class exist this method:

```
class test_ClikerBot(unittest.TestCase):    
   def test_clicker_bot(self):
```

Where is problem? I import this code from catalog studio recorder, and start learn python a week ago, because many things for me like magic and google help not every time (Sorry for bad English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would be ok if your `test_ClikerBot` class was an ordinary class. The point is that `unittest` is a very special framework, and `TestCase` classes are not meant to be used directly, but thru a `TestRunner` and a `TestLoader` that both do quite some magic under the hood. [This is partly documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#loading-and-running-tests), but you'll probably have to read the source code of the existing runners and loaders to really find out how to make the whole thing work. A good starting point might be the already existing GUI testrunner mentionned in the doc:

> The script Tools/unittestgui/unittestgui.py in the Python source 
>   distribution is a GUI tool for test discovery and execution